# WPF ComboBox, whenever bound data changed, set SelectedIndex to 0?

Tags: wpf, combobox, selectedindex

I couldn't find the right event to achieve the functionality.

TargetUpdated event didn't work.

setting SelectedIndex to 0 on xaml would only affect the first load of data.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

- Set `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` on the binding
- Add an event handler for `Binding.TargetUpdated`
- In that event handler register for `ItemsSource.CollectionChanged`
- In that event handler set the selected index to zero

The issue is most likely that you didn't set `NotifyonTargetUpdated` in the binding so the first event wasn't fired or that the collection was being updated but it was the same collection so the second event is necessary.

Here's a working example using a `ListBox` as the `ItemsControl` and a `MessageBox` as a proxy for doing whatever you want to do when the event fires.

Here is the markup:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Update Target" Click="ButtonUpdateTarget_Click"/>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Update Item" Click="ButtonUpdateItem_Click"/>
        <ListBox Name="listBox" Binding.TargetUpdated="ListBox_TargetUpdated" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

and here is the code-behind:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<string> items;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

void SetDataContext()
{
    DataContext = viewModel;
    viewModel.Items = new ObservableCollection<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
}

ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

private void ButtonUpdateTarget_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.Items = new ObservableCollection<string> { "xyz", "pdq" };
}

private void ButtonUpdateItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    viewModel.Items[0] = "xxx";
}

private void ListBox_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Target Updated!");
    (listBox.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(listBox_CollectionChanged);
}

void listBox_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item Updated!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [SourceUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sourceupdated.aspx) event?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. To overcome this problem, I used the following steps:

- create a TextBox
- Set visibility of TextBox to Collapsed
- Bind Text to `ListBox.Items.Count`

  ```
  <TextBox x:Name="txtCount" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=Items.Count, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
  ```
- In the `TextBox_TextChanged` event, set `SelectedIndex` to 0

  ```
  private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      int count = 0;

      if(int.TryParse(txtCount.Text,out count) && count>0)
          ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

  }
  ```